# Suppress automatically added namespace in etree Python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

```
<rootTag xmlns="model">
<tag>
```

I have an xml file with a namespace specified as above. I can use etree in Python to parse it, but after making changes and writing it back to the file, etree changes it to this

```
<rootTag xmlns:ns0="model">
<ns0:tag>
```

and prepended "ns0" to all the tags. I don't want that to happen. 
A sample program is as follows:

```
et = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse(xml_name)
root = (et.getroot())
root.find('.//*'+pattern).text = new_text
et.write(xml_name)
```

Is there someway to suppress this automatic change? Thanks

Comment: Please provide a sample file and a minimal program

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to tell lxml.etree.tostring(element) not to write namespaces in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004215/how-to-tell-lxml-etree-tostringelement-not-to-write-namespaces-in-python)

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55921412/python-elementtree-find-using-namespaces/55929533#55929533

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using [`register_namespace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.register_namespace) by using an empty string for the prefix...

```
ET.register_namespace("", "model")
```

Full working example...

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = """
<rootTag xmlns="model">
    <tag>foo</tag>
</rootTag>
"""

ET.register_namespace("", "model")

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
root.find("{model}tag").text = "bar"
print(ET.tostring(root).decode())
```

printed output...

```xml
<rootTag xmlns="model">
    <tag>bar</tag>
</rootTag>
```

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55921412/python-elementtree-find-using-namespaces/55929533#55929533) for another example.